# Mpi4py code does not stop running

Tags: python, parallel-processing, cluster-computing, hpc, mpi4py

I am working with a very basic python code (filename: `test_mpi.py`) to try out parallel programming in python using mpi4py. What I am trying to do is to have a two dimensional numpy array with zeros for all entries. And then use specific processors in a cluster to increase the value of specific elements of the numpy array.

Specifically, I have a 3*3 numpy matrix (`mat`) which has all elements as zeros. After my code finishes running (across multiple processors), I want the matrix to look like this:

```
mat = [[ 1.  2.  3.]
       [ 4.  5.  6.]
       [ 7.  8.  9.]]
```

This is a fairly simple task and I expect my code to finish running inside a few minutes(if not lesser time). My code keeps running for a very long time and doesn't stop execution (ultimately I have to delete the job after many hours.)

This is my code:

```
from __future__ import division
from mpi4py import MPI
import os
import time
import numpy as np

comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD
nproc = comm.Get_size()
rank = comm.Get_rank()

start_time = time.time()

mat = np.zeros((3,3))

comm.bcast([ mat , MPI.DOUBLE], root=0)


for proc in range(1, nproc):
    if rank == proc:
        print "I'm processor: ", rank
        var = proc
        comm.send( var, dest=0, tag = (proc*1000) ) 
        print "Processor: ", rank, " finished working."


if rank == 0:
    print "Hello! I'm the master processor, rank: ", rank 
    for i in range(0,dim):
        for j in range(0, dim):
            proc = ((i*j)+1)
            mat[i,j] += comm.recv(source=proc, tag=(proc*1000) )


     np.savetxt('mat.txt', mat) 



print time.time() - start_time
```

This is my job script for execution of this python code:

```
#!/bin/sh

#PBS -l nodes=2:ppn=16
#PBS -N test_mpi4py
#PBS -m abe
#PBS -l walltime=168:00:00
#PBS -j eo
#PBS -q physics

cd $PBS_O_WORKDIR
export OMP_NUM_THREADS=16
export I_MPI_PIN=off
echo 'This job started on: ' `date`

/opt/intel/impi/2018.0.128/intel64/bin/mpirun -np 32 python test_mpi.py
```

I use `qsub jobscriptname.sh` to run the job script. What am I missing here? I will appreciate any help here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code did not finish because some of the MPI communications did not complete.

MPI requires that for every send there should be exactly one receive.
Your first loop is executed by every MPI process rank independently, the condition `rank == proc` would be satisfied exactly once for each rank with the exception of `0` rank, therefore `comm.send` would be executed `nproc - 1` times. Your second loop is executed `dim * dim` times. Therefore `comm.recv` would also be executed `dim*dim` times. Unless `nproc - 1 == dim * dim`. The requirement would not be satisfied and some `recv` or `send` operations would be waiting to complete indefinitely. For your example `31 != 9`, so the communications would not complete until the walltime is exceeded.

In order to fix this error let us clarify the algorithm a bit. So we want to have each of the ranks from 1 to 9 to be responsible for one of the elements in a 3x3 matrix. Each process rank posts `comm.send` request. The requests are received in a certain order by process rank 0 and stored in the corresponding element of the matrix. The rest of the ranks if they are available do nothing.

Let us introduce three changes:

1. initialize the value for `dim`
2. move the conditional operator checking if we are processor rank 0 or not out of the loop
3. fix the computation of the rank corresponding to the element `mat[i,j]` which currently is not correct (e.g. for the central element `mat[1,1]` the rank should be 5, not 1 * 1 + 1 = 2)

### Code

Here is what I got after the modifications:

```
from __future__ import division
from mpi4py import MPI
import os
import time
import numpy as np

comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD
nproc = comm.Get_size()
rank = comm.Get_rank()

start_time = time.time()

dim = 3
mat = np.zeros((dim,dim))

comm.bcast([ mat , MPI.DOUBLE], root=0)

if rank > 0:
    if rank <= dim * dim:
        print "I'm processor: ", rank
        var = rank
        req = comm.send( var, dest=0, tag = (rank*1000) )
    print "Processor: ", rank, " finished working."
else:
    print "Hello! I'm the master processor, rank: ", rank 
    for i in range(0,dim):
        for j in range(0, dim):
            proc = ((i*dim)+j)+1
            if proc < nproc:
                mat[i,j] += comm.recv(source=proc, tag=(proc*1000) )
    np.savetxt('mat.txt', mat)
```

### Output

And here is the output:

```
mpirun -np 5 python mpi4.py
```

saves to `mat.txt` the following matrix

```
1.000000000000000000e+00 2.000000000000000000e+00 3.000000000000000000e+00
4.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00
0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00
```

And

```
mpirun -np 32 python mpi4.py
```

saves to `mat.txt` the following matrix

```
1.000000000000000000e+00 2.000000000000000000e+00 3.000000000000000000e+00
4.000000000000000000e+00 5.000000000000000000e+00 6.000000000000000000e+00
7.000000000000000000e+00 8.000000000000000000e+00 9.000000000000000000e+00
```

While 10 is the minimal number of process ranks that would produce the correct result.

Comment: Your answer worked. Many thanks for the answer and the wonderful explanation.